# Parse numbers and mutate produces only NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

# Read in the data
ds <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/parse_problem.csv")
str(ds)
# 'data.frame': 105 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Especie      : chr  "C_externa" "C_externa" "C_externa" "C_externa" ...
#  $ Rep          : chr  "R1" "R2" "R3" "R4" ...
#  $ Instar_IN    : chr  "1Instar" "1Instar" "1Instar" "1Instar" ...
#  $ Instar_PS    : chr  "ovo" "ovo" "ovo" "ovo" ...
#  $ Tentou_predar: int  3 25 20 36 12 0 1 10 0 14 ...
```

I'd like to `parse_number` using `mutate` for `Especie` factor for plotting purposes. I've tried the following:

```
ds.new <- ds %>% mutate(x_1=readr::parse_number(Especie),group = Especie)
summary(ds.new$x_1)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
#      NA      NA      NA     NaN      NA      NA     105
```

I don't know why it's not working and I've just NA. Please, any ideas?

```
dput(ds)
structure(list(Especie = c("C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", 
"C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", 
"C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", 
"C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", 
"C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", 
"C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", 
"C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", 
"C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", 
"C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", "C_externa", 
"C_externa", "C_externa", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", 
"C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", 
"C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", 
"C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", 
"C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", 
"C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", 
"C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", 
"C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", 
"C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", 
"C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana", 
"C_cubana", "C_cubana", "C_cubana"), Rep = c("R1", "R2", "R3", 
"R4", "R5", "R6", "R7", "R8", "R9", "R10", "R11", "R12", "R13", 
"R14", "R15", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7", "R8", 
"R9", "R10", "R11", "R12", "R13", "R14", "R15", "R1", "R2", "R3", 
"R4", "R5", "R6", "R7", "R8", "R9", "R10", "R11", "R12", "R13", 
"R14", "R15", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7", "R8", 
"R9", "R10", "R11", "R12", "R13", "R14", "R15", "R16", "R17", 
"R18", "R19", "R20", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7", 
"R8", "R9", "R10", "R11", "R12", "R13", "R14", "R15", "R16", 
"R17", "R18", "R19", "R20", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", 
"R7", "R8", "R9", "R10", "R11", "R12", "R13", "R14", "R15", "R16", 
"R17", "R18", "R19", "R20"), Instar_IN = c("1Instar", "1Instar", 
"1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", 
"1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", 
"1Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", 
"2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", 
"2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", 
"3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", 
"3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", 
"3Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", 
"1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", 
"1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", 
"1Instar", "1Instar", "1Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", 
"2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", 
"2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", 
"2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "2Instar", "3Instar", 
"3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", 
"3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", 
"3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", "3Instar", 
"3Instar"), Instar_PS = c("ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", "ovo", 
"ovo"), Tentou_predar = c(3L, 25L, 20L, 36L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 
0L, 14L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 35L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 22L, 0L, 2L, 9L, 54L, 57L, 26L, 17L, 18L, 34L, 2L, 
0L, 20L, 25L, 6L, 65L, 36L, 6L, 62L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-105L))
```

Comment: Your `Especie` column is a character which does not contain any numbers. Hence you get NAs. Perhaps you could clarify what you have in mind? Perhaps you are looking for `as.numeric(factor(ds$Especie))`?

Comment: Please include your sample data as code (ie, `dput(ds)`) and not as a link since links may become depreciated or change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

ds <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/parse_problem.csv")

ds %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Instar_IN), parse_number)
```

Hope this helps!